# How to stop a fixed positioning going negative

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am updating a site with responsive design, which has all the content in a 1000px width container that centres on the viewport. I want to used a fixed sidebar, but want the whole content still to stick to 1000px and be centred in the viewport, and when the viewport is less than 1000px, for the bootstrap responsive design to work. My current best attempt is as follows:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="page-content-wrapper"></div>
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

with css

```
#wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: calc((100vw - 1000px)/2);
    top: 0;
    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
#page-content-wrapper{
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 250px;
}
```

This works fine until the viewport is less than 1000px, at which time bootstrap works e.g. menus collapse,  but content starts disappearing to the left.  This is because the  wrapper left position goes negative for viewports less than 1000px.

How do I do stop content disappearing when the viewport is less than 1000px?

Comment: please provide demo or link so it will help us to solve the question.ty

Comment: Obviously the calculation of the `left` attribute will cause the negativity. Can't you alter the value for `left` by using media queries that notice when the viewport actually becomes narrower than 1000px?

Comment: why don't you use this - `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` to center the `wrapper` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SilentTremor's answer is a great way to approach this sort of problem. The exact code I used for my situation was

```
@media (min-width: 999px) {
  #wrapper{
    left: calc((100vw - 1000px)/2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create media equerry, or use predifined bootstrap media queries

```
@media (max-width: 999px) {
  #wrapper{
    left: calc((100vw - 800px)/2);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 799px) {
  #wrapper{
    left: calc((100vw - 400px)/2);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 399px) {
  #wrapper{
    left: calc((100vw - 200px)/2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great idea so I have upvoted it, but I think it should read ```min-width``` not ```max-width```.  Also it should be 1000px not 800px.

Comment: @Obromios well I tried to cover responsiveness of the page :)